# Get data where DateTime is a 15m interval

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I currently have an Entry model defined similar to this:

```
    field :var_name, type: String
    field :var_data, type: String
    field :var_date, type: DateTime
```

I have data generated throughout the day, and have been asked to return a report of data at 15 min intervals. All the entries where the DataTime field var_date is at 15 minute intervals of the hours.  i.e 12:00  12:15  12:30  12:45

I have a feeling this is might be simple but having a tough time at the moment with it, could anyone please help.

Some example data in the var_date I have is like this:

```
    2014-09-18T05:00:00+00:00
    2014-09-18T05:05:00+00:00
    2014-09-18T05:10:00+00:00
    2014-09-18T05:15:00+00:00
    2014-09-18T05:20:00+00:00
    2014-09-18T05:25:00+00:00
```

Comment: What report are you generating? Would be easiest to show you by example.

Comment: So, you could do this with a modulus operator and a where clause. First process will be to extract the time from the datetime stamp. Then create modulus operations for each of the intervals.

Comment: Why not use `crontab`?

Comment: @dddd1919 I get a batch of data at the end of each day and have to sort through it.

Comment: @wdberkeley The report is just a list of the var_name, var_data, var_date where var_date is at a 15minute time interval of an hour. i.e 0, 15, 30 or 45 minutes past the hour.

An example output would be:

`Process Time  133  2014-09-18T05:15:00+00:00`

Comment: And you can use `whenever` to run rake task at a special time.

Comment: @dddd1919 It a batch file at the end of the data, I get a dump of the data I have to work with that and can't set up cron jobs or whenever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explanation

---

I ended up doing this in a much simpler way code wise, after a couple of hours this morning trying to use the MongoDB aggregation framework as suggested in another answer.

Not sure why I didn't think of it yesterday and this may not be as efficient (would love advice on that) but basically for each `Entry` I simply checked the minutes of the `var_date` field to see if it matched any 15 minute interval.

`0, 15, 30 or 45`

If it did I added it to `@entries15min`, which gave me the data I needed.

#### Code I ended up with

---

```
entries = Entry.all.order('var_date ASC')

@entries15min = []

entries.each do |entry|
  if [0,15,30,45].include? entry.var_date.min
    @entries15min << entry
  end
end
```

Thank you for all the suggestions, hope this helps others.

Comment: While this was the answer the worked to my particular issue and given the environment I was working, I do believe that Neil Lunn answer may prove a better answer. However I have not created a working solution based on that answer, so marking this as the answer as I know it works for my question and restrictions on database access.

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is your answer. You can either use epoch timestamps as your output values or accept the general date aggregation operators:

Assuming a "class" called `Entry` here, use the `.collection` accessor to get the underlying driver functions.

This can be done using the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/):

```
Entry.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => {
            "dayOfYear" => { "$dayOfYear" => "$var_date" },
            "interval" => {
                "$subtract" => [
                    { "$minute" => "$var_date" },
                    { "$mod" => [
                       { "$minute" => "$var_date" },
                       15
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },
       "count" => { "$sum" => 1 }
    }}
])
```

Or in the basic "epoch timestamp" form by subtracting the current date object value from the initial epoch value in order to represent a timestamp in numeric form:

```
Entry.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group" => {
        "_id" => {
            "$subtract" => [
                { "$subtract" => [ "$var_date", DateTime.new(1970,1,1) ] },
                { "$mod" => [
                    { "$subtract" => [ "$var_date", DateTime.new(1970,1,1) ] },
                    1000 * 60 * 15
                ]}
            ]
        },
        "count" => { "$sum" => 1 }
    }}
 ])
```

So in each case the `_id` used for grouping here represents a 15 minute interval within the hour, and whatever fields you wish to include are applied to ["grouping operators"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) in order to achieve totals or other functions, as per the example of "counting" events within the period.

At any rate, you need to look into the aggregation framework operators and specifically [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as a pipeline stage to accumulate results.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I couldn't get this working as I needed.   The aggregation framework seems really powerful. I worked using this example as a starting point this morning but thought of a simpler way of getting the result I needed which I have posted in my own answer. I have a lot to learn about the deeper functionality of Mongodb I think.

Comment: @KevinMann What I basically propose is "do you really want what you propose as a possible answer?" I don't think you do. If you truly want timed group intervals then you want them to be consistent and based on the real hour intervals. You also **don't** want to have this processing on your application client as is what your code does. In all the years I have been doing this, the common wisdom is that the "database" server is more powerful than the application server. And that extends to "cluster/sharded" environments. Let the "database" do the work. That is smart.

Comment: @KevinMann Just one more comment for "comment" limitations on posts. The point is "what looks like" *less lines of code* is almost *never* more efficient. Spent enough time programming assembler to know that this is true.

Comment: Thank you letting the database do the work sounds like good advice. I do want the results at 00, 15, 30 and 45 minutes past the hour for this particular project.  It is based on taking samples of the data at those time slots.  I do understand less lines code isn't more efficient, which is why I asked for advice in my answer, your comments help with that. I will look into doing more work at the database level.

Comment: @KevinMann The Modulo operator here means that the number is expected to be "divisible" by a factor of 15. So all of 15,30, and 45 will work. And it makes sense since 15 is actually the grouping from 0 to 15. If you now understand how this is done.

Comment: @KevinMann Oh and yes. 45-0 is a valid interval with a modulo as well as the modulo of 0 is 0